# ERROR 4 Start tag expected, '<' not found (in n/a - line 1, column 1)

Tags: php, symfony, service

I'm getting this error when I add a new service:

> [ERROR 4] Start tag expected, '<' not found (in n/a - line 1, column 1)

This is the new `services.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    acme_foo.class: Acme\FooBundle\Services\Foos

services:
    acme_foo:
        class: %acme_foo.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine]
```

There are no tabs in this file, only spaces. This is the `DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme_foo');

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

and the `DependencyInjection/AcmeFooExtension.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class RedconviveSubscriptionExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Any idea of where the error is? It seems to be related to `services.yml`, but I've checked it and doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
$loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader
```

to

```
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader
```

in `DependencyInjection/AcmeFooExtension.php`. Because you are loading `yml` file.